# Rebol -q option buggy?

Tags: c#, rebol

I want to redirect rebol output to C# with -q options but I still get in the end:

> REBOL/View 2.7.7.3.1 1-Jan-2010
>   Copyright 2000-2010 REBOL
>   Technologies.  All rights reserved.
>   REBOL is a trademark of REBOL
>   Technologies. WWW.REBOL.COM
>
> Type desktop to start the Viewtop.

C# Source code for context usage:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;   
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\rebol";
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\rebol\rebol.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-qw --do \"firstname: {world} print build-markup {hello <%firstname%>} \"";    
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
MessageBox.Show(output);
```

If I run rebol directly from Windows I have the same bug:

> C:\rebol\rebol.exe -q --do "firstname:
>   {world} print build-markup {hello
>   <%firstname%>}"

will output in rebol console:

```
hello world
REBOL/View 2.7.7.3.1 1-Jan-2010
Copyright 2000-2010 REBOL Technologies.  All rights reserved.
REBOL is a trademark of REBOL Technologies. WWW.REBOL.COM


Type desktop to start the Viewtop.
>>
```

Comment: What happens if you run the same command from a console window?

Comment: Also, you're getting the standard output before WaitForExit.

Comment: see my post update below: I have same bug if I run from dos shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `--do` to run script code, you will need to add a `quit` (or `q`) to the end of this script to have REBOL/View quit. Also, to prevent the Viewtop from starting, add the `-v` option. So the following should do the trick:

```
rebol.exe -qvw --do "print {hello} quit"
```

The reason is a strange interplay between `--do` and other interpreter options. I think this could well be considered a bug, but in any case, it has been this way for quite some time.

Comment: Thanks you saved my end of year Happy One :) Yes that's a bug for me would be great if bug was solved or documented but RT has so much to do !